# How to return null value if the query has no corresponding value?

Tags: mysql

i've a query

```
select c.name as companyname, u.name,u.email,u.role,a.date 
from useraccount u, company c, audittrial a 
where 
    u.status='active' 
    and u.companyid=c.id 
    and 
    (
        u.companyid=a.companyID 
        and a.activity like 'User activated%' 
        and a.email=u.email
    ) 
order by u.companyid desc 
limit 10
```

So if the following part doesnt't satisfy,

```
(
    u.companyid=a.companyID 
    and a.activity like 'User activated%' 
    and a.email=u.email
)
```

no rows will be returned..

but i want to return the result of the following query

```
select c.name as companyname, u.name,u.email,u.role,a.date 
from useraccount u, company c, audittrial a 
where 
    u.status='active' 
    and u.companyid=c.id 
order by u.companyid desc 
limit 10
```

but to add that, i should return the date if available and return null value if date is not available..

how can i do this?

Comment: first things first - use specific JOIN instead of the technique you are using

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly. Is the idea that you definitely want the data from your useraccount and company rows, and **if available** you also want the audittrail data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple tables combined with a `where` clause are effectively an inner join:

```
select *  from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id
```

is the same as

```
select *  from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

To make the audit trail optional, change it to a `left join`:

```
select  ...
from    useraccount u
join    company c
on      u.companyid = c.id
left join
        audittrial a
on      a.activity like 'User activated%' 
        and a.email = u.email
order by
        u.companyid desc 
limit   10
```

By the way, I think the proper spelling is audit tr **ai** l.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name as companyname, u.name,u.email,u.role,
       IF(a.date!='', a.date, null) AS audit_date

FROM "rest of query"
```